# Anyway to reuse <ng-template>

Tags: angular

My angular component looks something like this

```
<p-listbox>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <mat-icon>find_in_page</mat-icon> {{item.name}}
  </ng-template>
</p-listbox>

<p-listbox>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <mat-icon>find_in_page</mat-icon> {{item.name}}
  </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

I have two listboxes (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/listbox) , each has the same template for rendering a list item.
Now I have duplicate code in each of the  tags.

Is there any way I can reduce code and reuse a centrally defined  for the list item

Comment: can you check for `ngTemplateOutLet`

Comment: You can create a new component <app-list> and move the above snippets to the component and then call the component whereever u need.

Comment: @user1608841 Use of ngTemplateOutlet does not work. We need a way to plugin the <ng-template> inline

Comment: @ShivamGupta any specific reaso why it will not work ?

You can even pass contect to ngTemplateOutlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simply to use a nested `<ng-template>`

```
<p-listbox>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templatePItem; context: {$implicit: item}">
    </ng-container>   
  <ng-template>
</p-listbox>

<ng-template #templatePItem let-item>
  <!-- Define your template for the item -->
  <mat-icon>find_page</mat-icon> {{item.value}}
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the standard component route

component.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-plist-component',
  templateUrl: './plist-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plist-component.scss'],
})
export class PlistComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input item:any

}
```

component.html

```
<p-listbox>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <mat-icon>find_in_page</mat-icon> {{item.name}}
  </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

Usage:

```
<app-plist-component [item]="item"></app-plist-component>
```

---

Another option. Probably not what you were after but you could loop them...

```
<p-listbox *ngFor="let item of [{name:'Fred'},{name:'Joe'}]">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <mat-icon>find_in_page</mat-icon> {{item.name}}
  </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

Comment: This would be cool if I had the list boxes stacked right next to each other. But that is not the case. You're use of *ngFor go me thinking if there would be a way out using other simple structural elements. Any other ideas ?

Comment: That was a quick bandaid to reduce code in a one time situation. Why not just create a little component? Basic code added to my answer.

Comment: I have quite a few input items/ as well a output handlers for the <p-listbox>. I was not sure how creating a nested component would impact performance.

Comment: I have answered my own question. You can have a look. The answer clicked right when I stopped looking so hard :D